# Time Complexity of two for loops

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

So I know that the time complexity of:

```
for(i;i<x;i++){
   for(y;y<x;y++){
      //code
   }
}
```

is n^2

but would:

```
for(i;i<x;i++){
   //code
}
for(y;y<x;y++){
   //code
}
```

be n+n?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Since the big-O notation is not about comparing absolute complexity, but only relative one, O(n+n) is in fact the same as O(n). Each time you double x, your code will take twice as long as it did before and that means O(n). Whether your code runs through 2, 4 or 20 loops doesn't matter, since whatever time it takes for 100 elements, it will take twice the time for 200 elements and 100 times the time for 10'000 elements, no matter how much time of that is spent within which loop.

That's why big-O is not saying anything about absolute speed. Whoever assumes that a O(n^2) function f() is always slower than a O(log n) function g(), is wrong. The big-O notation only says that if you keep increasing n, there will be a point where g() is going to overtake f() in speed, however, if n always stays below that point in practice, then f() can always be faster than g() in real program code.

Example 1
Let's assume f(x) takes 5 ms for a single element and g(x) takes 100 ms for a single element, but f(x) is O(n^2), g(x) is O(log2 n). The time graph will look like this:

[image]
Note: Up to 7 elements, f(x) is faster, even though it is O(n^2).
For 8 or more elements, g(x) is faster.

Example 2
A binary search is O(log n), an ideal hashtable (without collisions) is O(1), but trust me, a hashtable is not always always faster than a binary search in reality. Using a good hash function, hashing a string can take more time than the whole binary search does. On the other hand, using a poor hash function creates plenty collisions and the more collisions means that your hashtable lookup will not really be O(1), because most hashtables solve collisions in a way that will make lookups either O(log2 n) or even O(n).

Comment: +1 for your answer.  Just an addition to your explanation -> O(k*n) = O(n) where k is any non-negative constant and n>=0. In this case O(2n) = O(n). In general, O(k*f(n)) = O(f(n)) where f(n) is a function of n. For more on asymptotic notations refer to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Your second paragraph states that O(n^2) is not always slower than O(log n). Can you give a concrete example where that is the case? If I [plot n^2 and log n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bn%5E2%2C+log+n%7D+from+x%3D0+to+10), I don't see the curves intersecting. O(log n) always seems to be faster. Where is my thinking mistake?

Comment: @Lernkurve I deleted my previous comment and instead migrated the example it contained to my answer above.

Answer (score 18):

It would be 2n, so yes, you're right.

It's usually just expressed as O(n) though, seeing as it is linear rather than quadratic.

It does of course depend on what code is within the loops, but I guess you already know that.