# Time Complexity of serial loops with different input

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know that complexity of two serial loops with the same number of iterations is *O(n)*, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872120/time-complexity-of-two-for-loops), but what if the loops are based on different inputs? for example:

```
for(i;i<m;i++){
   //code
}
for(y;y<n;y++){
   //code
}
```

It would be *O(m+n)*?

Comment: If the body of each loop executes in O(1), then yes, it would be O(m+n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely :)

The first loop, if it's not empty, has a multiple of `m` operations.

The second loop has a multiple of `n` operations.

Using both one after the other gives you `O(m+n)`.